# SQL command returns invalid object name database.table

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlcommand

I run this code:

```
                    SqlConnection polaczenie;
                    polaczenie = new SqlConnection(dane_polaczenia);
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    cmd.Connection = polaczenie;
                    polaczenie.Open();
                    cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM test.test";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

After executing I got exception `Invalid object name 'test.test'.`

Database and table values are correct.

How to specify `database.table` in `CommandText` correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM test.dbo.test";
```

or

```
                cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM test..test";
```